# MeteorJS ES6 syntax fails only when importing NPM package. Building same code inside repo works fine

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

I've built a small npm package of ~200 lines which runs a healthcheck. It uses ES6 syntax. When I publish and then import to a meteor project an error is throw around `let checks = [];` saying `SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode`.

The meteor project uses ES6 and `let` variables are used throughout.

I've take this npm package and built it into a file within my meteor project, therefore not importing. This runs fine and my healthcheck works. For some reason when I import however it breaks.

npm package code:
`let checks = [];`

error:

```
let checks = [];
^^^
SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at /Users/.../configuration-service/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:287:30
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/.../.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.1_2.1xe2w4b.28mr++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at /Users/.../configuration-service/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
```

I'd expect ES6 syntax to not be a problem, given it's already used throughout the project which imports this small package. I'm not sure why ES6 doesn't work only when used as an import node module. If I copy/paste the same exact code into a file within my project it doesn't complain.

Comment: Did you wrote the NPM package yourself or is it installed from the registry?

Comment: @Jankapunkt I wrote it myself and published it/installed it from the registry

Comment: Would you mind adding the link to it?

Comment: it's a private package so that probably wouldn't be useful, right?